# Calculate new position of player

Tags: math, position

Edit: I will summerize my question since it is very long (Thanks Len for pointing it out)

What I'm trying to find out is to get a new position of a player after an X amount of time.
The following variables are known:
- Speed
- Length between the 2 points
- Source position (X, Y)
- Destination position (X, Y)

How can I calculate a position between the source and destion with these variables given?

For example:

source: 0, 0
destination: 10, 0
speed: 1

so after 1 second the players position would be 1, 0

The code below works but it's quite long so I'm looking for something shorter/more logical

======================================================================

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to calculate a new position of a player ingame.

This code is server sided used to track a player(It's a emulator so I don't have access to the clients code).

The collision detection of the server works fine I'm using bresenham's line algorithm and a raycast to determine at which point a collision happens.

Once I deteremined the collision I calculate the length of the path the player is about to walk and also the total time.

I would like to know the new position of a player each second.

This is the code I'm currently using. It's in C++ but I am porting the server to C# and I haven't written the code in C# yet.

```
        // Difference between the source X - destination X 
        //and source y - destionation Y
        float xDiff, yDiff;

        xDiff = xDes - xSrc;
        yDiff = yDes - ySrc;

        float walkingLength = 0.00F;

        float NewX = xDiff * xDiff;
        float NewY = yDiff * yDiff;

        walkingLength = NewX + NewY;

        walkingLength = sqrt(walkingLength);



        const float PI = 3.14159265F;
        float Angle = 0.00F;

        if(xDes >= xSrc && yDes >= ySrc)
        {
            Angle = atanf((yDiff / xDiff));
            Angle = Angle * 180 / PI;
        }
        else if(xDes < xSrc && yDes >= ySrc)
        {
            Angle = atanf((-xDiff / yDiff));
            Angle = Angle * 180 / PI;
            Angle += 90.00F;
        }
        else if(xDes < xSrc && yDes < ySrc)
        {
            Angle = atanf((yDiff / xDiff));
            Angle = Angle * 180 / PI;
            Angle += 180.00F;
        }
        else if(xDes >= xSrc && yDes < ySrc)
        {
            Angle = atanf((xDiff / -yDiff));
            Angle = Angle * 180 / PI;
            Angle += 270.00F;
        }

        float WalkingTime = (float)walkingLength / (float)speed;



        bool Done = false;
        float i = 0;
        while(i < walkingLength)
        {
            if(Done == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(WalkingTime >= 1000)
            {
                Sleep(1000);
                i += speed;
                WalkTime -= 1000;
            }
            else
            {
                Sleep(WalkTime);
                i += speed * WalkTime;
                WalkTime -= 1000;
                Done = true;
            }

            if(Angle >= 0 && Angle < 90)
            {
                float xNew = cosf(Angle * PI / 180) * i;
                float yNew = sinf(Angle * PI / 180) * i;

                float NewCharacterX = xSrc + xNew;
                float NewCharacterY = ySrc + yNew;
            }
```

I have cut the last part of the loop since it's just 3 other else if statements with 3 other angle conditions and the only change is the sin and cos.

The given speed parameter is the speed/second.

The code above works but as you can see it's quite long so I'm looking for a new way to calculate this.

btw, don't mind the while loop to calculate each new position I'm going to use a timer in C#

Thank you very much

Comment: There's so much code here, you might find that people are reluctant to help, if only because it's not so obvious what the real question is. Could you try to summarise at the top of your post what exactly you need help with, and what you've tried so far to achieve it?

Comment: Are `WalkTime` and `WalkingTime` the same variable? Is `speed` the number of coordinates per second, or millisecond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the angles. Trigonometry are both code- and time-intensive. You should use vectors instead.

Here is an rewrite of your code:

```cpp
float xDiff = xDes - xSrc;
float yDiff = yDes - ySrc;

// Euclidean distance from source to destination
float walkingLength = sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);

float WalkingTime = walkingLength / speed;

bool Done = false;
float i = 0;
while(i < walkingLength && !Done)
{
    if(WalkingTime >= 1f)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        i += speed;
        WalkingTime -= 1f;
    }
    else
    {
        Sleep((int) (WalkingTime * 1000f));
        i += speed * WalkingTime;
        WalkingTime -= 1f;
        Done = true;
    }

    float xNew = xDiff / walkingLength * i;
    float yNew = yDiff / walkingLength * i;

    float NewCharacterX = xSrc + xNew;
    float NewCharacterY = ySrc + yNew;
}
```

`xDiff / walkingLength` will be the same as `cosf(Angle * PI / 180)` in your code.